# Can I download emails recived between dates in JavaMail (IMAP)?

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

Is there any way to download all emails that are recived between date?

i.e.:

```
Date from = ...
Date to = ...
Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages(from, to);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Folder#search(SearchTerm)](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/search/SearchTerm.html). Implement a concrete subclass of `SearchTerm` that overrides the [SearchTerm#match(Message)](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/search/SearchTerm.html#match%28javax.mail.Message%29) method. Have it return true if the date of the `Message` matches what you're interested in.

Comment: This searching is made by server or application?

Comment: @user2365209 The code goes in your application. JavaMail will call your code to determine what messages match. You can then use that information to get the messages that fit your parameters.

Comment: This approach will cause all the searching to be done on the client.

Answer (score 1):

Use two ReceivedDateTerms and an AndTerm to search for messages where the date is between the two values.  Once you have the Message objects, you can download or access whatever you need.

Comment: The IMAP protocol only supports dates with days, not times.  If you need to search based on times you can use Folder.search to narrow the list down to days and then use Message.match to find messages within the specified times.  The latter will be done on the client by downloading the required information for each message.